# How would you organize and separate global state with context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-hooks

I have more of a conceptual question

From what I understand, all child react components are re rendered every time the state is changed in a parent component. For context to work it has to be located in the root parent component and pass down state to all child components through the provider.

So is there any way around re rendering all your child components when you update the global context state?

I have seen people implement multiple context objects but why would this matter since the state is still being changed the root parent so all child components are still being re rendered right? The context provider is just the wrapper but not where the state is actually being updated.

or not having one root parent component but instead middleman parent components that pass only the required global state to only certain child components. But how would you realistically organize this and how would it work with routing?

Please let me know if im mistaken or missing something.

My context looks like this and I need a better way to orginize it

```
  <Context.Provider
          value={{
            //Reducer1
            stateProp1: stateReducer1.stateprop1,
            stateProp2: stateReducer1.stateprop2,
            dispatchContextTrue: () => handleDispatchTrue(),
            dispatchContextFalse: () => handleDispatchFalse(),

            //Auth Reducer
            authState: stateAuthReducer.is_authenticated,
            profileState:  stateAuthReducer.profile,
            dbProfileState: stateAuthReducer.db_profile,
            handleUserLogin: () => handleLogin(),
            handleUserLogout: () => handleLogout(),
            handleUserAddProfile: (profile) => handleAddProfile(profile),
            handleUserRemoveProfile: () => handleRemoveProfile(),
            handleAddDBProfile: (profile) => handleDBProfile(profile),
            handleRemoveDBProfile: () => handleRemoveDBProfile(),

            //Form Reducer
            useContextChangeState: stateFormReducer.user_textChange,
            useContextSubmitState: stateFormReducer.user_textSubmit,
            useContextSubmit: (event) => handleFormSubmit(event),
            useContextChange: (event) => handleFormChange(event),

            //Posts Reducer
            postsState: statePostsReducer.posts,
            commentsState:  statePostsReducer.comments,
            userPostsState: statePostsReducer.user_posts,
            searchPostsState: statePostsReducer.db_search_posts,
            handleAddPosts: (posts) => handleSetPosts(posts),
            handleRemovePosts: () => handleRemovePosts(),
            handleAddComments: (comments) => handleSetComments(comments),
            handleRemoveComments: () => handleRemoveComments(),
            handleAddUserPosts: (posts) => handleSetUserPosts(posts),
            handleRemoveUserPosts: () => handleRemoveUserPosts(),
            handleSetSearchPosts: (posts) => handleAddSearchPosts(posts),
            handleRemoveSearchPosts: () => handleRemoveSearchPosts(),

            //User Reducer
            otherUserProfileState: stateUserReducer.db_other_user_profile,
            otherUserPostsState: stateUserReducer.db_other_user_posts,
            userMessagesState: stateUserReducer.user_messages,
            handleAddOtherUserProfile: (profile) => handleSetOtherUserProfile(profile),
            handleRemoveOtherUserProfile: () => handleRemoveOtherUserProfile(),
            handleAddOtherUserPosts: (posts) => handleSetOtherUserPosts(posts),
            handleRemoveOtherUserPosts: () => handleRemoveOtherUserPosts(),
            handleAddUserMessages: (messages) => handleSetUserMessages(messages),
            handleRemoveUserMessages: () => handleRemoveUserMessages(),

            //Handle auth
            handleAuth: (props) => handleAuthentication(props),
            authObj: auth
          }}>
          <Routes />
      </Context.Provider>
```